# 300Mbs on a wi-fi router are available for each connection? Or that bandwidth is shared among the devices?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

So I have a Wi-fi router that operates with a 300Mbs capacity.

What I want to know is:

Do those 300Mbps are shared among all devices connected to the router?

Or does each wireless connection to the router can run on 300Mbps simultaneously?

Comment: Wireless networking is like a hub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 300 Mbps is shared between all users. WiFi is a shared medium, there is only so much spectrum available.

If one user is using say 100 Mb, 200 Mb would theoretically be left for other users. Keep in mind that you will never* be able to utilize the full 300 Mb due to overheads.

*Feel free to prove me wrong

Comment: Awesome! I was guessing it was shared. Just want to be sure about it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If the router has multiple bands, each band could support 300Mb/s, depending on the routers internal hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, the bandwidth is shared. One thing to note though, is a lot of entry level and home networking kit still use 100Mbps ethernet connections, so devices wired to the router (such as a home server, NAS box etc) are a bigger limiting factor than the wireless itself.

And of course even if you did have the full 300Mbps, that doesn't improve the fact that your internet connection is probably a fraction of that!

Answer (score 0):

WiFi at 2GHz has longer reach than that using 5GHz.
The possible throughput will dimish quite quickly outside a certain circle, with just "a few" meters of increasing distance and any obstacles in the radio wave path.
Make the obstacles contain ceramic, stone, metal (e.g. concrete reinforcing bars) and you can expect even less throughput.

Ref: https://www.google.se/search?q=wifi+propagation - google search
Some specific details: http://en.kioskea.net/contents/832-propagation-of-radio-waves-802-11